# CEF 3 offscreen rendering and page source

Tags: c++, chromium, chromium-embedded

today i'm working with Chromium Embedded Framework 3.

I have everything set up, compiled and executed. Everything works fine.

Now I want to read the page source after everything is rendered and JavaScript is executed.
I would also like to get the buffer from the offscreen rendering.

My basic application structure is:

**App implements CefApp, CefBrowserProcessHandler and CefRenderProcessHandler**

**Handler implements CefClient, CefDisplayHandler, CefLifeSpanHandler, CefLoadHandler and CefRenderHandler**

**Visitor implements CefStringVisitor**

In App::OnContextInitialized() i'm executing

> CreateBrowser(window_info, handler.get(), "http://www.google.com/",
>   browser_settings, NULL);

while

> window_info.SetAsWindowless(NULL, true);

Now is App::OnContextCreated() only called if i run CEF3 in single-mode with

> main_settings.single_process = true;

otherwise it's never called. In App::OnContextCreated() im doing

> browser->GetMainFrame()->GetSource(new Visitor());

to get the page source and it works, but the method is called multiple times and seems not to executing JavaScript at this point.

**My question is now what's the best point to read the page source AFTER everything is rendered and JavaScript is executed ?**

Also Handler::OnPaint() is never called while Handler::GetViewRect() is.

regards

Norwido

Answer (score 1):

OnContextCreated runs in the Renderer process, that's probably why it works only in single process mode. You should call GetSource in CefLoadHandler::OnLoadEnd or OnLoadingStateChange that run in the Browser process.

Not implementing all the necessary callbacks in CefRenderHandler may be the cause of the OnPaint callback not being called. Read the doc comments in the header files.

Comment: I used CefLoadHandler::OnLoadEnd before but it's fired at every frame, seems OnLoadingStateChange is the way to go. Big Thanks :)

Comment: @Norwido OnLoadEnd may also work if you add a condition: `if (browser->GetMainFrame()->GetIdentifier() == frame->GetIdentifier())`. Don't forget to +1 / accept the answer if that helped you.